# How can I change my PowerShell commands' output to have different colors?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

How can I change my PowerShell commands to look like [Windows development setup with WSL2, ZSH, VSCode, and more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oF6gLyhQDdw&t=498s&ab_channel=ChristianLempa)? You can check at timestamp: 3:55, also refer this image:

[image: Commands]

- I had installed the xcad theme & followed all instructions from [Make Windows Terminal look amazing!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AK2JE2YsKto&t=883s&ab_channel=ChristianLempa)  but I could not get it to look like I wanted. if I type `dir` in PowerShell only the "dir" is changed to purple but the resulting query was complete white.
- Also the picture I have attached is the snippet from Ubuntu running through WSL on Windows & I tried to do the same configuration over Ubuntu but it does not look the way I want it.

Can someone let me know I only want to change the PowerShell command results to be in this way, I do not want to change anything with Ubuntu. Is there any way?

Comment: Hello, what is your exact and specific question? In the title yyou're talking about prompt, then  you're showing a screenshot of a command result.

Comment: What you want is trivial with Windows Terminal, as you can customize each profile, and WSL2 and PowerShell are distinct profiles but you probably knew this since the screenshot is of Windows Terminal

Comment: @Destroy666, to clarify, I want my command result to look like the screenshot I have posted on the question. Thanks for your response, do you have any idea ?  Thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound, Yes, Can I ask you what do you mean by trivial here ? Is that name of a software ? Thanks.

Comment: Google "oh my posh"

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, Thanks, I have already installed oh my posh, it changes the color of the command prompt, I want to change the colours of the command results as well i.e. you can see the result of ls -l results in a structured tree of all the items in different shades of purple.

Comment: @Anton - You don't know the meaning of the word of "trivial"?  The name of the program is Windows Terminal, it is trivial, to configure multple profiles for different shells by using Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to colorize command output in PowerShell, but there's no universal way to do it for all commands.

To colorize dir/file info specifically, you can use this module, for instance: [PSColor](https://github.com/Davlind/PSColor). It overrides the default output for commonly used commands. Steps:

1. Install it with [PSGet](http://psget.net/):

```
Install-Module PSColor
```

2. Add `Import-Module PSColor` to your PowerShell profile file(s). The location for your PowerShell version can be found with `echo $PROFILE`, e.g:

```
C:\Users\[user]\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

for PowerShell 7.

3. You can also configure colors in the same file, as shown in [README](https://github.com/Davlind/PSColor#configuration):

```
$global:PSColor = @{
    File = @{
        Default    = @{ Color = 'White' }
        Directory  = @{ Color = 'Cyan'}
        Hidden     = @{ Color = 'DarkGray'; Pattern = '^\.' } 
        Code       = @{ Color = 'Magenta'; Pattern = '\.(java|c|cpp|cs|js|css|html)$' }
        Executable = @{ Color = 'Red'; Pattern = '\.(exe|bat|cmd|py|pl|ps1|psm1|vbs|rb|reg)$' }
        Text       = @{ Color = 'Yellow'; Pattern = '\.(txt|cfg|conf|ini|csv|log|config|xml|yml|md|markdown)$' }
        Compressed = @{ Color = 'Green'; Pattern = '\.(zip|tar|gz|rar|jar|war)$' }
    }
}
```

---

Newer PowerShell versions (7.2+) also have `$PSSTYLE` variable that can be modified for some of the output. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#psstyle) and [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features?view=powershell-7.3#psansirenderingfileinfo) of what can be modified.

You can also check all available properties by echoing `$PSSTYLE`.

Comment: Hi Thanks, my terminal looks much better know, Can I know how your terminal looks ? I'm running a different color scheme & it exactly looks like the one in the screenshot I uploaded in my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Np. I rarely use PowerShell, mostly through scripts that I don't colorize. On Windows I prefer clink (easier to colorize in general) or anything through WSL.